# How do I RegRead from a non-standard hex key?

Tags: registry, autohotkey

I'm making a script to toggle Loudness Equalization on a hotkey.
Very simple and should only take 3 seconds to do.

Here's my .AHK script so far:

```
^F11::
RunAsAdmin(){

    RegRead, eq, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render\{f58675a4-6f8d-4ffb-8ea2-554239885fcb}\FxProperties, ({e0a941a0-88a2-4df5-8d6b-dd20bb06e8fb},4)

    Msgbox % eq

    RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render\{f58675a4-6f8d-4ffb-8ea2-554239885fcb}\FxProperties, "{e0a941a0-88a2-4df5-8d6b-dd20bb06e8fb},4", % not eq

    return
}
```

Msgbox is returning blank, so I assume the key isn't found.
The KeyValue is exactly as you see it `{e0a941a0-88a2-4df5-8d6b-dd20bb06e8fb},4` with a `,4` behind it.

Will need some help on this, pretty hard to google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone in the discord helped me.

I just had to escape the `,` in the hex key,

so it became {e0a941a0-88a2-4df5-8d6b-dd20bb06e8fb}`,4